# Jekyll: can't we loop in the posts (and display the list) from each post?

Tags: html, ruby, loops, jekyll, liquid

I want to display a list of posts in a category page: this loop works.
But I also want to display this list on each of these posts: it's the same loop but it doesn't work.

There is my Jekyll loop:

```
{% for post in site.categories.[include.nomrecueil] reversed %}
  <li>{{ post.title }</li>
{% endfor %}
```

## Short version

My loop is not fetching posts depending on the layout used.
I have the following structure:

```
categoryA
    | index.md
    | categoryB
        | index.md
        | _posts
            | article.md
```

I have two layouts that include the same loop. My loop in `categoryB/index.md` is working, but the same in `article.md` doesn’t work. Any idea why? Can't we loop in the posts (and display the list) from each post?

## Details

You may need more information, so you can take a look at [the repo](https://github.com/inwardmovement/inwardmovement.github.io) if you need. The loop is at [line 35 of the include nav-poemes.html](https://github.com/inwardmovement/inwardmovement.github.io/blob/master/_includes/nav-poemes.html#L35-L37) which is included in two layouts: a) [recueil.html](https://github.com/inwardmovement/inwardmovement.github.io/blob/master/_layouts/recueil.html) and b) [poem.html](https://github.com/inwardmovement/inwardmovement.github.io/blob/master/_layouts/poem.html). The loop outputs correctly in the `index.md` that calls the `recueil.html` layout, but not in the `article.md` that calls the `poem.html` layout.

I checked that the include parameter `nomrecueil` that's in the loop is well passed through both layouts. No posts are fetched in the second layout with the same loop...
Am I using Jekyll the wrong way or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know why... but this works (which must have something to do with the 'contains' statement):

```
{% assing includenomrecueil = include.nomrecueil %}
<ul>
  {% for category in site.categories %}
    {% assign catfirst = category | first %}
    {% if includenomrecueil contains catfirst %}
      {% for posts in category %}
        {% for p in posts reversed %}
          <li>...</li>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

In your code the variable comes through. I even tried to add spaces to the variable and remove them (to make sure it is a string). Remarkable is that this works:

```
{% for post in site.categories['fleurs-persistantes'] reversed %}
  <li>...</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Even when `{{ include.nomrecueil }}` outputs `fleurs-persistantes`, while at the same time this does not work:

```
{% for post in site.categories[include.nomrecueil] reversed %}
  <li>...</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Really strange! I do not understand it.

Comment: yes and what is strange is that my original loop works on the category page but not on the single post page... Anyways I'm so happy your loop works ! thank you very much man for getting involved and solving my problem! :) I'll see if I can simplify a bit the loop. I have to try Hugo to see if their loops are more efficient, but so far so good I have a working Jekyll site.

Comment: Tip: See Jekyllcodex.org for solutions without plugins.